# Observation: "Take back" is used in impolite speech, while "Bring back" is used in polite speech. Is there any basis to this?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, differences, phrasal-verbs, politeness

I'm an English teacher working with an advanced student. They asked me to teach them how to ask for help or support when things aren't going they way they should. I decided to teach him that it is often best to use indirect speech when asking for help, and these two sentences arose in my planning:

1. I’m afraid my food isn’t heated thoroughly, could you please bring it back to the kitchen
2. My food is cold, please take it back to the kitchen.

I naturally switch between "bring back" and "take back" in the polite, and less polite versions. If I play and switch them around, each sentence sounds more or less polite, accordingly. Is this just me thinking too hard, or is there some basis for this?

Comment: In the first example sentence, the use of "bring it back" would imply to me that the speaker was in the kitchen.

Comment: (1) doesn't work as a paraphrase, as @Killing Time says, and it's hard to see where paraphrases _could_ be used. //  Your triple hedging in (1) ('I’m afraid  ... ', 'could you', as well as the 'please') makes any comparison infelicitous here. // You probably have a point; 'take' sounds inherently more abrupt/confrontational than 'bring' (back my Bonny to me?)

Comment: There's also the 'dismissive' flavour of _take_ as opposed to the 'accepting' hint of _bring_.

Comment: If the food had been exceptionally wonderful rather than cold you could have said "Please take my compliments to the chef". Nothing to do with politeness or otherwise, everything to do with the direction of travel.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think you've captured the essence of my feeling with that, but I think that the nuance of that sensation gets lost behind the "direction of travel" aspect that everyone else is focusing on.

Comment: As an English teacher, you are probably aware that your comma splices (in the examples) would be seen as unacceptable by some. While I'm not in the 'comma splice ... incorrect!' camp, I'd certainly rewrite these examples (and I can't make sense of (1)).

Answer (score 3):

> Observation: “Take back” is used in impolite speech, while “Bring back” is used in polite speech. Is there any basis to this?

None whatsoever.

Both are the imperative form.

To take usually implies **away from** the speaker. To bring usually implies **towards** the speaker.